# Using Jasmine's spyOn / andReturn to mock fs.readFileSync()

Tags: node.js, express, jasmine, tdd

I'm trying to mock the response of fs.readFileSync() so I can test that my code is returning some data in my config file. Obviously I don't want to be testing the contents of my config file.

I'm trying to test this code in (api.js)

```
var fs = require('fs');
var config = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('configure.json', 'utf8'));

var Api = {
    api_key: config['api-key'],
    heartbeat_id: config['resource-id'],
};
```

If I can mock what `fs.readFileSync` returns then I can have it return some test values. My test looks like this:

```
var api = require('./api');
var fs = require('fs');

describe('Api object contains correct details', function(){
    it('Has an API key of "test API"', function(){
        spyOn(fs, 'readFileSync').andReturn(`{
            "api-key": "test API",
            "resource-id": "Resource ID"
        }`);
        expect(api.api_key).toBe("test API");
    });
});
```

The test is failing and returning the value in my actual config file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `api.js`, you are not exporting anything to be used by other modules, so when in your test file you do...

```
var api = require('./api');
```

... you are executing the `api.js` file straight away. This means that, by the time your test creates a spy on `fs.readFileSync`, that function has already been used by `api.js` and your value injection is not used in the test scope.

One way of achieving what you want would be to create a function in `api.js` that retrieves the configuration on demand, and encapsulate this function within a `module.exports` block. Then, in your test, requiring `api.js` leaves the test ready to retrieve the configuration, so if you create a spy on `fs.readFileSync` before doing the retrieval, the spy is the one that will be called and you can assert on the mocked values.

Using Jasmine 2.4.1, this is how it would look:

#### src/api.js

```
var fs = require('fs');

module.exports = {
    getConfig: function() {
        var config = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./src/configure.json', 'utf8'));

        var Api = {
            api_key: config['api-key'],
            heartbeat_id: config['resource-id'],
        };

        return Api;
    }
}
```

#### spec/api.spec.js

```
var api = require('../src/api'); // fs.readFileSync hasn't been used yet
var fs = require('fs');

describe('Api object contains correct details', function(){
    it('Has an API key of "test API"', function() {
        spyOn(fs, 'readFileSync').and.returnValue(`{ // here it's being mocked
            "api-key": "test API",
            "resource-id": "Resource ID"
        }`);
        var config = api.getConfig(); // now we are using the mock
        expect(config.api_key).toBe("test API");
    });
});
```

Comment: This helped me a *a lot*. I needed to run tests specific to Windows and Mac on any OS and with this I was able to mock the Node.js OS plackage by doing `spyOn(os, 'platform').and.returnValue("win64");` and `spyOn(os, 'platform').and.returnValue("darwin");` Great stuff. Thank you.